# Does performance degrade between iOS 3.1 and 4.1 for the iPod Touch 2nd gen?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, upgrade

I noticed a considerable performance degradation when updating to iOS 4.0; enough to downgrade back to 3.1.x. Has that issue been completely resolved in 4.1? Having to downgrade again would be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made the updates, and I didn't notice anything about a performance degradation.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying there doesn't seem to be any performance problem, or you only now noticed a performance problem? Did you notice the issue with the 4.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally gotten around to trying the 4.1 upgrade, and the responsiveness seems perfectly acceptable now.