# Update ipod touch 2g to iOS 4?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I have an iPod Touch (second generation) with iOS 3.1.2. Will I lose battery life or performance if I update to the latest iOS (4.2.1)?

These are the closest answers I could find:

- [iOS 4.2 on iPod Touch 2d Gen: is it worth it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/ios-4-2-on-ipod-touch-2d-gen-is-it-worth-it)
- [Does performance degrade between iOS 3.1 and 4.1 for the iPod Touch 2nd gen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/does-performance-degrade-between-ios-3-1-and-4-1-for-the-ipod-touch-2nd-gen)

However, these relate to somewhat different versions of iOS.

Comment: I think if there's any lags that you experience, it's mostly because of your perception after handling iPhone 4's and iPod touch 4th Gen in the stores (that feels much faster).

Comment: The other effect that happens when a new OS release happens is older apps are not tuned or interact poorly with the changes. The developers almost always clean that up with a patch, so the chances of having a poor experience with 4.2.1 is much lower now that it's been out for a while.

Answer (score 4):

I second that. No problems. I am sending you this post from my iPod touch 2nd generation with iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running the latest version of iOS that my second generation iPod touch will support, and it's working fine. I don't notice a performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended for you to upgrade your device to the latest version as it has been provided much more functions than you think, and do not just focus on the loss of performance stuff. More importantly, iOS4 shows better compatibility of the iOS Apps.